# RTC alarm vs System alarm on ARM (STM32)

Tags: stm32, alarm, real-time-clock

I'm learning the [stm32F4](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f4-series.html). There are some confusions I can't really understand.

What's the difference between RTC alarm and original system alarm. I only know that the RTC can save more power but nothing else. Can anyone explain to me or make some example for the difference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There should be appropriate white-papers and documentation available: I've tried to make the question slightly more generic (as it's an ARM-based microprocessor so the domains might overlap): Good luck!

Comment: There is no domain overlap this is all within the realm of the chip vendor not related to ARM.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this [application note](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/7a/9c/de/da/84/e7/47/8a/DM00025071.pdf/files/DM00025071.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00025071.pdf). This should elaborate on the functionality of a RTC and the functionality it offers.

In short: the real-time clock (RTC) embedded in STM32 microcontrollers acts as an independent BCD timer/ counter. The RTC can be used to provide a full-featured calendar, alarm, periodic wakeup unit, digital calibration, synchronization, time stamp, and advanced tamper detection.

A RTC can also be more precise than a internal SysClk.